How to automatically select/highlight text in a tkinter entry widget?
I would like to have an entry widget with some default text in it, where the text contained in the entry widget is automatically "highlighted" (in the same way as when you drag your mouse over text), such that if you want to edit the entry you can just start typing and it will replace the text rather than requiring you to manually highlight and delete the default text, as many website do.
Here's some example code:

from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def myClick():
    hello = "Hello " + my_entry.get()
    my_label.configure(text=hello)

my_entry = Entry(root)
my_entry.insert(END, "Enter your name here.")
my_entry.pack()
my_button = Button(root, text="Click Me!", command=myClick)
my_button.pack()
my_label = Label(root, text="")
my_label.pack()

root.mainloop()

I've tried searching about this in every way I can think of, but it's hard to find. Thank you in advance for any help.

You can simply make the entry widget to get the keyboard focus using .focus_set() and highlight all the text using .selection_range(0, END):
...

my_entry.focus_set() # get the keyboard focus
my_entry.selection_range(0, END) # highlight all the text

root.mainloop()


If I wanted to select all the text when the box is clicked on, how would I do that? I've tried using an if statement with root.focus_get(), but I can't figure out what I need to check if that's equivalent to. When I try to set a string to root.focus_get() or the text field of a label to that directly I either get 'none' or no output whatsoever.

You can call the suggested code inside a callback bound to the event <FocusIn>.
